# DotNetOpenAuth 3.4 and Facebook as an identity provider/trusted provider

Tags: facebook

DotNetOpenAuth 3.4, Facebook

Does Facebook function as a *provider* (similar to Yahoo! or Google)? If so, does anyone have a pointer to example DotNetOpenAuth code?

Answer (score 3):

Facebook supports OAuth 2.0, which a [CTP of DotNetOpenAuth](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/CTP/OAuth2/) supports and includes a sample for that demonstrates figuring out who the user is.

Comment: Also, you'll want to take a look at this answer to get started with the DotNetOpenAuth CTP.  It's an excellent walkthrough:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821747/facebook-twitter-with-dotnetopenauth/5259556#5259556

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not currently function as a provider, only as a relying party/service provider. I need to use Facebook Connect to authenticate a Facebook user within my app.