# Facebook/ Twitter with dotnetopenauth?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I've pretty much got OpenID working using the [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) library. Now I would like users to be able to use **Facebook** and **Twitter** to login.

This requires `OAuth` so I am looking for a tutorial on how to use DotNetOpenAuth OAuth.

I'm having trouble trying to find some simple tutorials on how to do this.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I used [http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2009/03/twitter-oauth-with-net/](http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2009/03/twitter-oauth-with-net/) as a reference for twitter's OAuth. It took some custom work and I ended up wrapped a custom membership provider around it, but it worked pretty easily once I wrapped my head around everything. I haven't used facebook connect, yet so I can't offer much help there.

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth includes a sample in the OAuthConsumer project of logging in with Twitter. The DotNetOpenAuth OAuth 2.0 CTP includes a Facebook login sample in the OAuthConsumer project as well.

Comment: @Andrew Arnott - Hmm I had a problem with loading up the samples(I had a question on stack but for some reason I accepted an answer that I never tried out). You commented on that post so maybe you can elaborate on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671367/where-are-tutorials-for-dotnetopenauth-and-how-to-solve-compile-error-in-its-samp

Comment: I also find that written tutorials are helpful too as when I look into the samples I feel a bit over whelmed and not even sure where to start. I like to see a nice simple example before going straight into full blown scenario.

Comment: I found a tutorial for twitter http://blog.techcle.com/2010/03/20/simple-oauth-integration-for-twitter-in-asp-net-mvc/ that I think might be good. However I noticed there is a .dll called DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock what does not seem to come nuget. I am wondering if you know why. I still would like to try to get the sample ones to work.

Comment: Hmm the tutorial might be out of date. I can't get InMemoryTokenManager to work. It says I can't use it because it is an internal class.

Comment: @Andrew Arnott - I got the sample to work. I am wondering is there an example in the solution to make the openid ajax through mvc?

Comment: I ok I am getting the twitter example to work but I am just wondering can I control the url through code instead of through the application settings at twitters homepage?

Comment: Well the return url that I setup for twitter(on their page) does not seem to work. Does dotnetopenauth override it?

Comment: @Andrew Arnott - I can't find also DotNetOpenAuth OAuth 2.0 CTP seems like all the download links I find are dead.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

At the time of me answering this question, DotNetOpenAuth has a [public Community Tech Preview (CTP) which is available to download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/CTP/OAuth2/).

[image: Pew Pew]

1. Download that source code. Should be a .7z file. You can use [7-Zip to unzip the code](http://www.7-zip.org/) if you don't already have it (it's free).
2. Open up the **samples** source code solution in Visual Studio. I'm using VS2010 but I think there's also a VS2008 solution file.

[image: More Pew Pew]

3. Now, open up the web.config file for the `OAuthClient` project.
   [image]
4. Next, edit the following settings :-

   `<!-- Facebook sign-up: http://developers.facebook.com/setup/ -->`

   `<add key="facebookAppID" value="------"/>`

   `<add key="facebookAppSecret" value="------------"/>`

You can get these values from your [application on Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/).

5. Debug/Run the OAuthClient Web Application. This will start an instance of Cassini/Visual Studio Developer Server and a web browser should open:

[image]

Voilà! you can now connect to Facebook to log in.

If you get errors, then you need to make sure that:

1. You've manually changed the Facebook app settings in your `web.config` file.
2. You've correctly setup your app settings in the Facebook developer website.

Comment: I had to change int in FacebookGraph.cs to long and to fetch user email I added an Email property as well. Not sure if this is the only way to get it working though..but thanks for your help :)

Comment: +1.  Note to others: The DotNetOpenAuth sample `OAuthClient` with Facebook settings is not available in versions 3.4.5.10202 or 3.4.7.11121, but it is available in version 3.5.0.10357 and 4.0.0.11165.  You have to use at least the version shown by @Pure.Krome here.

Comment: Does anyone know why the FB login is only available in the 3.5 versions? and not in the new ones?

Comment: Facebook are on a different draft of OAuth 2.0.  The version that dotnetopenauth uses is a later version.  It sucks.

Comment: For up to date code you can refer to their [github repo](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples/tree/master/src/OAuth/OAuthClient)