# facebook login url from a c# application

Tags: c#, facebook

How can I found out the url that pops the Facebook Login page when I want to connect to facebook from a c# application? Can someone please tell me what is the url and give me an example? THX

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Comment: i just to have on my desktop the explorer page. can you tell me if this is possible? in the facebook.sdk the connect retuns the exporer page. How can i do that using the url?

Comment: appId:'000' should i give it in ' ' or no? I have an error says that the url is not correct. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Comment: what is the redirect url? how do i know what url it is?

Comment: how do i know if the client did click allow or not? can you please tell me? and what is the full url for allow? in the documentation u send it says: http://www.example.com/response#
  access_token=...&
  expires_in=3600
WHAT IS AFTER access_token=...?? what does the ... mean? THX

Comment: That the facebook takes care of. If the client clicks, allow, facebook will redirect the user to the RedirectURL that u have given to facebook with an auth Token string/response. You just have to do a GetResponse() and check if it is authenticated. 
Try the demo project in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/OpenIdFormsAuth.aspx. With this u can achieve the single sign on with any site that expose a open id endpoint.

Comment: Similar thread.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821747/facebook-twitter-with-dotnetopenauth

Comment: Can you give me an example of RedirectURL with the auth Token string/response. And please can you tell me how to do that GetResponse? PLEASE?i am working in c#.

Comment: I did  a webpage recently like the one u mentioned. There is a free-source library called DotNetOpenAuth.dll. The code project link i have attached uses it for google/twitter etc. You can download the demo proj and run it(It will not work if u r behind proxy-firewall). The second link is for facebook. Both has the GetResponse methods' sample code. All you need to do is add the DotNetOpenAut.dll as reference and copy the GetResponse() method. Modify the web.config as per your website name and convenience.

Comment: thx a lot. can you give me the link if the dll/sample code? I am new to .getresponse() and i am having problems of how to do it

Comment: There are links in the comments. Those links have the option for downloading source code and samples. Anyways posting it again
[Link1] http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/CTP/OAuth2/
[Link2] http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/OpenIdFormsAuth.aspx
[Link3]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821747/facebook-twitter-with-dotnetopenauth