# DotNetOpenAuth v4 not working with Facebook authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, dotnetopenauth

As [DotNetOpenAuth and Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6666447/340760) question says, the authentication is not working with Facebook using DotNetOpenAuth `v4.0.0.11165`

Instead of using a previous version I was wondering if there is a way to fix it, so I am thinking in modifying the `ProcessUserAuthorization` method in order to do some tweak to fix it, but I have no idea how it works.

```
public new IAuthorizationState ProcessUserAuthorization(HttpRequestInfo request = null)
{
    return base.ProcessUserAuthorization(request);
}
```

Is it possible to fix modifying this method? Or is it much more complex?

Is there a way to fix it or I will have to get a previous version?

Answer (score 0):

More recent versions of DotNetOpenAuth *do* work with Facebook.  Please upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

Facebook does not implement the OpenID protocol, it is not an OpenID provider.
Sadly, it will never work. You have to handle facebook authentication in a diffrent way in your application.
The only way you can use facebook as a authentication provider for your site is the one described by facebook here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/ and it does not involve OpenID in any way.

Comment: The question doesn't mention OpenID, so I don't know what prompted this answer.  In fact the question makes reference to OAuth methods in DNOA, so the question is applicable.