# Integrating OAuth with .Net

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth, authorization

I am currently using Facebook Connect and have plans to use other sources for user authentication (ie. Google). How do I integrate it with .NET? I want to do things such as be able to get the currently logged in user, authorize a user when they attempt to do an action (similar to standard authorization attributes), etc.

I don't really know where to start. I have my own table in the database for storing user information such as their ID, access token, and time until the access token expires. Right now I do all OAuth stuff client-side via javascript.

Also, I am creating a single page website. That is probably an important detail.

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821747/facebook-twitter-with-dotnetopenauth

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at DotNetOpenAuth?

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: I'm looking at it but all their documentation is no longer working. All demos no longer work, etc.