# DotNetOpenAuth - Facebook - How can I authenticate users without forcing them to install a Facebook App?

Tags: facebook, dotnetopenauth

I have implemented the sample application provided by DotNetOpenAuth as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259556/127880).

As you can see below, this is requiring that the user installs this facebook application.

[image]

I simply want to allow users to use their facebook login for my vanilla ASP.NET website.

**Is there some way to prevent them from having to install a facebook application?**

Update: Stackexchange Facebook login doesn't have an "install" button. It simply has a dialog requesting various permissions. This is much preferred in my case.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This will work until Facebook forces everybody to use the "Enhanced Auth Dialog"**

You can fix this dialog by going into your advanced application settings:

[image]

Changing this setting will cause the dialog to appear as you suggested in your excellent question.

[image]

Comment: Great answer Brian Webster.  While correct for now, this will only work until they force all apps over to the new auth dialog.