# Facebook C# SDK Windows Application

Tags: c#, facebook

Does anyone has a sample application, which can show the way on how to authenticate a user and get his access token, so that other functions can be used.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this guide should help you: http://multitiered.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/getting-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/

**UPDATE**:
Well it seems like that guide refers to an SDK which has been depreciated. I recommend you to  download [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) which has a [sample for Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259556/337294) as well.

Comment: Thanks, I went through this article, but it is a web application, i am looking for a windows application.

Comment: Please consider mentioning your requirements more explicitly in the question. also check out http://nuget.org/packages/Facebook.Sample.Winforms.Login I haven't tested it myself. The source of the package is at http://csharpsdk.org/

Comment: I want to get the list of pages of a user, using my application. I am able to do it statically by passing access token. But I am not getting how to fetch user access token, dynamically...!