# Implement Login using Facebook,Twitter,Linkin in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I had to integrate Login using Google,Twitter,Facebook into my
asp.net web forms application and i'm not using MVC.
I searched around and found a open source library for the task.

```
http://dotnetopenauth.net/
```

But the site doesn't have much info on how to implement it in asp.net web form applications.
any links on how to implement this using dotnetopenoauth library would be appreciated.And no MVC, simple Asp.net Web forms application

Comment: Please check link below and see if it can help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821747/facebook-twitter-with-dotnetopenauth

Answer (score 1):

If you open a project with the 4.5 template provided much of the code is already written, you just have to look into.

See also:

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-45/oauth-in-the-default-aspnet-45-templates
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx